# how do I separate user params vs Action Pack params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, actionpack

I have a Rails application where user parameters are all provided via a RESTful API with JSON parameters.  Specifically, there is no client-side HTML form from which the user posts data: it's raw JSON.

So to create a new Car entry, the user might:

```
POST www.mysite.com/api/car
model=Ford&year=2012
```

In my app, by the time I receive this, the Action Pack values are intermingled with the user values in the params[] hash, so I get:

```
params = {:model=>"Ford", :year=>"2012", :format=>"json", :action=>"create", :controller=>"api/cars"}
```

What's the best way to separate the user-generated parameters from parameters generated by Action Pack?  The best I can think of is to delete the latter:

```
car_params = params.reject {|k,v| [:format, :action, :controller].member?(k)}
car = car.new(car_params)
```

but that doesn't smell right.  Is there a better way?  (For example, can I get Action Pack to encapsulate the user supplied params into a single hash and pass that as a single element of params[]?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if it can help, but I'd just create a method in application_controller :

```
def user_params
  return params.reject {|k,v| [:format, :action, :controller].member?(k)}
end
```

So throughout the code, you can just use `user_params` when you don't want ActionPack params

Comment: Yeah, I put a function like that in my application_helper.rb file.  I was hoping that there was some trick to make it so I don't need it at all!

Comment: And since this is Rails: `params.exclude(:format, :action, :controller)` is way more concise.

Comment: When I try your more concise `params.exclude(:format, :action, :controller)` I get "undefined method `exclude`"